# LaTeX book recommendation?

Tags: latex

[EN]
Can anyone recommend a good LaTeX book for beginners, preferably in German?

[DE]
Kann mir bitte jemand ein gutes LaTeX-Einsteiger-Buch empfehlen, vorzugsweise in deutscher Sprache?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Because of some other book recommendation questions on SO I didn't expect this question to be unsolicited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`lshort` is available [in german on CTAN](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/lshort/german/l2kurz2.pdf).